# Find the critical value of given statistical problem, t-distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

My solution doesn't match the one given in my course, however I can't quite see what I've done wrong. Can someone give me a heads-up?

## Problem

Given the following:

- $y: N(2,3)$
- $z: \chi^2(7 d.f.)$

$$P((y-2)^2>a^2z)=0.9$$
Find the critical value for $a$.
Rearranging the equation:
$$P(3\frac{(y-2)}{3}>a\sqrt{\frac{z}{7}}\sqrt{7})=0.9$$

Now y got standarised, so i substitute it to  $y_s=\frac{(y-2)}{3}$
$$P(\frac{y_s}{\sqrt{\frac{z}{7}}}>a\frac{\sqrt{7}}{3})=0.9$$

My book states that $\frac{y_s}{\sqrt{\frac{z}{7}}}$ now is a $t$-distribution with ($7 d.f.$)
Using an online $t$-distribution calculator i get the value $1.415$ for $t_{0.9}(7 d.f.)$
Because of the symmetry, we can invert the sign
$$P(-1.415\frac{3}{\sqrt{7}}<a)=0.1$$
$$\leftrightarrow P(-1.6045<a)=0.1$$
So I'd conclude that for the critical value  $a=-1.6045$

However the given solution says: $a= 0.1477$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**
You made a mistake in this step:

$$P((y-2)^2>a^2z)=0.9 \implies P\left(3\frac{(y-2)}{3}>a\sqrt{\frac{z}{7}}\sqrt{7}\right)=0.9$$

What you should have found was:

$$P((y-2)^2>a^2z)=0.9 \implies P\left(3\left|\frac{(y-2)}{3}\right|>\left|a\right|\sqrt{\frac{z}{7}}\sqrt{7}\right)=0.9$$

If we simplify this and assume $a\geq 0$, then we get:

$$P\left(\left|3\frac{(y-2)}{3}\right|>a\sqrt{\frac{z}{7}}\sqrt{7}\right) =0.9 \implies P\left(-a\sqrt{\frac{z}{7}}\sqrt{7} > 3\frac{(y-2)}{3}\;\textrm{or}\;3\frac{(y-2)}{3}>a\sqrt{\frac{z}{7}}\sqrt{7}\right) =0.9 $$

$$\implies P\left(-a\frac{\sqrt{7}}{3} > \frac{y_s}{\sqrt{\frac{z}{7}}}\;\textrm{or}\;\frac{y_s}{\sqrt{\frac{z}{7}}}>a\frac{\sqrt{7}}{3}\right) = 0.9$$

As your book says $\frac{y_s}{\sqrt{\frac{z}{7}}} \sim t_7$, so by symmetry, this is equivalent to finding $a$ such that:

$$2P\left(\frac{y_s}{\sqrt{\frac{z}{7}}}<-a\frac{\sqrt{7}}{3}\right) = 0.9$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I did from there: 
Substituting: $\frac{y_s}{\sqrt{\frac{z}{7}}}=U_t$ 

$$P(U_t<-a\frac{\sqrt{7}}{3})=0.45$$
Using the online t-dist. calc for $t_{.45}$, the critical value $t_p=-0.13$
$$P(\frac{3}{\sqrt{7}}(-0.13)<-a)=0.45$$
$$\frac{3}{\sqrt{7}}(-0.13)<-a$$
$$\frac{3}{\sqrt{7}}(0.13)=0.147406$$
Thus, the critical value is now correct - aside some rounding error ! Thanks for the help!